# Line style not updated when using gnuplot within pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I have a large data file with multiple columns. This makes it impossible for me to add multiple `\addplot` commands manually, so I am using `gnuplot` from within `pgfplots`. The problem is that `gnuplot` does not seem to utilise `cycle list` and all columns plotted are the same style. Is there a way for `gnuplot` to change the line style with every new column? Ideally, it will have exactly the same behaviour as using numerous `\addplot` commands, and also utilise custom `cycle list`s if possible.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=\columnwidth,
      height=\columnwidth,]

    \addplot+ gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {%
      set key outside;
      plot for [col=2:6] 'data.dat' using 1:col;
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

## Data File | `data.txt`:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0
20001   0.036388    0.028517    -0.033069   -0.034961   -0.025119
40001   0.078273    0.041198    -0.05016    -0.040372   -0.036597
60001   0.083334    0.080893    -0.067594   -0.062035   -0.048915
80001   0.10042 0.097744    -0.08017    -0.086433   -0.083851
1e+05   0.13486 0.12073 -0.097362   -0.10287    -0.093411
1.2e+05 0.15235 0.15038 -0.10748    -0.11208    -0.10857
1.4e+05 0.1604  0.15882 -0.11528    -0.15034    -0.12262
1.6e+05 0.18981 0.19139 -0.13932    -0.15833    -0.12653
1.8e+05 0.2069  0.21622 -0.13932    -0.16647    -0.15685
2e+05 0.21894 0.22313 -0.14568  -0.19297  -0.2045
```

## Result:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have different line styles for the different data columns, you have to use separate `\addplot` commands. Fortunately, you don't have to repeat the commands manually: instead, you can loop over the columns using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1   0   0   0   0   0
20001   0.036388    0.028517    -0.033069   -0.034961   -0.025119
40001   0.078273    0.041198    -0.05016    -0.040372   -0.036597
60001   0.083334    0.080893    -0.067594   -0.062035   -0.048915
80001   0.10042 0.097744    -0.08017    -0.086433   -0.083851
1e+05   0.13486 0.12073 -0.097362   -0.10287    -0.093411
1.2e+05 0.15235 0.15038 -0.10748    -0.11208    -0.10857
1.4e+05 0.1604  0.15882 -0.11528    -0.15034    -0.12262
1.6e+05 0.18981 0.19139 -0.13932    -0.15833    -0.12653
1.8e+05 0.2069  0.21622 -0.13932    -0.16647    -0.15685
2e+05 0.21894 0.22313 -0.14568  -0.19297  -0.2045
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=\columnwidth,
      height=\columnwidth,]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,6}{
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {%
      set key outside;
      plot 'data.dat' using 1:#1;
    };
    }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really need to add a donate button in your profile, Jake. `:-)` Am I right to assume that this would work with `\addplot+ table[x index=0,y index=#1] ...` (taking care to use zero-indexing)? Is there any reason to prefer `gnuplot`, other than plotting huge data files?

Comment: Glad to be of help! I would say the main reason for using `gnuplot` as a backend for PGFPlots is when you want to plot very complicated functions, or when you want to downsample large data files, because `gnuplot` is much faster in both those cases. If you want to plot all data points from a large file (without downsampling), using `gnuplot` won't speed things up very much, since PGFPlots still needs to parse all the points (in your example, all `gnuplot` is basically doing is to copy all the data to a new file, which is then plotted as if you hadn't used `gnuplot` at all).

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question: Yes, you could simply do `\addplot table[x index=0,y index=#1]` to get the same result (no need for the `+` if you're not providing any options to `\addplot`, by the way).